# Combine two xml records using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have the follwing data as an input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orderbackup>
    <edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData" amount="227.00000" refundmethod="VISA" backendriid="674256" />
    <edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData" amount="227.00000" refundmethod="VISA" backendriid="663754" />
    <edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData" amount="251.50000" refundmethod="VISA" backendriid="663304" />
    <ppcextdata attributename="account" searchvalue="XXXX" ppcpayinst_id="674256" />
    <ppcextdata attributename="account" searchvalue="YYYY" ppcpayinst_id="663754" />
    <ppcextdata attributename="account" searchvalue="ZZZZ" ppcpayinst_id="663304" />
</orderbackup>
```

I want to end up with:

```
<edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData" amount="227.00000" refundmethod="VISA" account="XXXX"/>
<edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData" amount="227.00000" refundmethod="VISA" account="YYYY"/>
<edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData" amount="251.50000" refundmethod="VISA" account="ZZZZ"/>
```

backendriid and ppcpayinst_id are the same.  I want to take the searchvalue from ppcextdata and add it as account to the edprefinst by matching the backendriid to the ppcpayinst_id

I can't think of a way in xslt to make this happen.  Any ideas?  I'm pretty new to this, so go easy on me (for now...)

Comment: Do you want an inner-join, left-outer-join or right-outer-join?  I.e. what to do when a `backendriid` exists without a matching `ppcpayinst_id` or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option...

**XML Input**

```
<orderbackup>
    <edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData" amount="227.00000" refundmethod="VISA" backendriid="674256" />
    <edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData" amount="227.00000" refundmethod="VISA" backendriid="663754" />
    <edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData" amount="251.50000" refundmethod="VISA" backendriid="663304" />
    <ppcextdata attributename="account" searchvalue="XXXX" ppcpayinst_id="674256" />
    <ppcextdata attributename="account" searchvalue="YYYY" ppcpayinst_id="663754" />
    <ppcextdata attributename="account" searchvalue="ZZZZ" ppcpayinst_id="663304" />
</orderbackup>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="edprefinst"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="edprefinst">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='backendriid')]|
                following-sibling::ppcextdata[@ppcpayinst_id=current()/@backendriid]/@searchvalue"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@searchvalue">
        <xsl:attribute name="account">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData"
            amount="227.00000"
            refundmethod="VISA"
            account="XXXX"/>
<edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData"
            amount="227.00000"
            refundmethod="VISA"
            account="YYYY"/>
<edprefinst paymentsystem="FirstData"
            amount="251.50000"
            refundmethod="VISA"
            account="ZZZZ"/>
```

I'm using `xsl:apply-templates` instead of directly outputting a new `account` attribute so that it's not created if a corresponding `ppcextdata/@searchvalue` isn't found.

Comment: Turned out to be a little more complicated than I thought.  There was more data I had to filter on, but your solution put me on the right path.